# CLions aligns everything to the left on entering closing curle, how to reset styles?

Tags: c++, coding-style, clion

CLion does some crazy and bad formatting on any closing curly brace entering.

[image]

Setting / changing style doesn't help

---

Compiling goes ok, so this is not due to syntax error.

---

I have sent a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36944

But how can I make formatter less annoying meanwhile? It breaks my formatting even if I copy paste the code.

Comment: Have you tried asking CLion to automatically reindent your code? Maybe a syntax error above is causing this weirdness.

Comment: @Botje it could be, but is not the case

Answer (score 0):

The reformatting CLion does is based on "Settings" - "Editor" - "Code style". Check specifically C/C++ language, "Tabs and indents".

Also check if there is `.editorconfig` file in your project, and a respective plugin installed in CLion.

Check if there is any other plugin that the file type is associated with in "Settings" - "Editor" - "File types".

If these don't help, file a bug.